# How to change a parent class variable from child class in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just starting out with Unity, and I'm making a basic 2d game using OOP principles for the characters. 
I've created a general enemy class called **EnemyController** and it has a child called **BasicEnemy**.

The idea is that when the enemy is spawned (between two points, which are a bed and a bar in this case), it either moves to the left or right and starts to patrol between the objects.
I'm using raycasting for this, and so far when the enemy hits either of those points, I've gotten the ray to flip along with the sprite. 
I can't seem to get the sprite to move in the newly flipped direction.

I've tried to modify the **moveSpeed** variable in the parent class, and I've tried to write my own movement functions **LeftMove** and **RightMove**.

My code is below.

This is the code for the Parent class:

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //transform for each of the enemies
    protected Transform enemyTransform;
    protected Vector2 startPosition;
    protected int damageValue, healthLevel;
    public int moveSpeed;
    protected int randNum;
    protected Rigidbody2D rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        enemyTransform = transform;
        startPosition = enemyTransform.position;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        randNum = Random.Range(1,3);
        // Debug.Log(randNum);

        if(randNum == 1) {
            Debug.Log("Moves Left at the start");
        } if(randNum == 2) {
            Debug.Log("Moves Right at the start");
            Flip(); 
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move(); 
    }

    protected virtual void Move()
    {
        if(randNum == 1) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        if(randNum == 2) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    public void Flip() {
        Vector3 enemyScale = transform.localScale;
        enemyScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = enemyScale;
    }

}
```

This is the code for the Child class:

```
public class BasicEnemy : EnemyController
{
    //Origin, Direction, Range for Raycasting.
    public Transform rayOriginPoint;
    private Vector2 rayDir = new Vector2(-1,0);
    public float range;

    //GameObjects that it should hit
    GameObject bar, bed;
    EnemyController parentClass;
    private void Start()
    {
        bar = GameObject.Find("minibar");
        bed = GameObject.Find("bed");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitObject = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOriginPoint.position,rayDir,range);
        Debug.DrawRay(rayOriginPoint.position,rayDir*range);

        if(hitObject == true) {
            if(hitObject.collider.name == bed.name) {
                Debug.Log(hitObject.collider.name);
                Flip();
                rayDir *= -1;
                LeftMove();
            }
            if(hitObject.collider.name == bar.name) {
                Debug.Log(hitObject.collider.name);
                Flip();
                rayDir *= -1;
                RightMove();
            }
        }
    }

    void LeftMove() {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-1, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    void RightMove(){
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(1, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just flip the sprite rather than change the scale? then use x/y as the natural axis they come on

Comment: @BugFinder won't that be the same as the Flip function I've written? As is, the sprite flips around. Could you please give me a code sample to understand? :)

Comment: GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true; transform.scale changes other things.

Comment: @BugFinder there's a few colliders and stuff that will need to be flipped too. That's why I've used the transform.scale bit. Mostly cuz I'm a little new to this.

Comment: It looks as though randNum changes if your enemy moves in + or - move direction and this never changes in your Flip function

Comment: @Prodigle so randNum is just there at the start to make the sprite either go left or right at the start of the level. I used flip to literally flip the sprit and its components around.

Comment: Definitely rotate on the Y-Axis 180 degrees, making the x-scale -1 will do some weird stuff to your child objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move(); 
    }
protected virtual void Move()
{
    if(randNum == 1) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    if(randNum == 2) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

The above block in your base controller tells your enemy which direction to move in based on randNum.

```
void LeftMove() {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-1, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    void RightMove(){
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(1, rb.velocity.y);
    }
```

This block in your inherited controller flips the velocity.

Immediately after the velocity is flipped from Left/Right move, the FixedUpdate calls and calls Move which then changes velocity back to what it was in randNum

Proposed Solution:
Store a bool directionRight, randomize it's value at creation,

in your fixedUpdate-Move

```
if(directionRight)
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
else
   rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
```

have your flip function call directionRight =!directionRight to flip direction.
No longer any need for your move left/right functions

Comment: I get the logic of what you're saying. I still can't figure out a way to fix it though. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: sure, writing now

Comment: I tried your solution out. So what happens is that the boolean value that is in `start()` is set to **false** when the sprite moves left, and **true** when it moves right, and then when `Move()` is called through `FixedUpdate()`, the boolean value is reset to **false**. 
That happens, and I have a "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at `rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by overriding the parent function in the child class.

```
private bool facingRight;

    private void Start()
    {
        bar = GameObject.Find("minibar");
        bed = GameObject.Find("bed");

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitObject = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOriginPoint.position,rayDir,range);
        Debug.DrawRay(rayOriginPoint.position,rayDir*range);

        if(hitObject == true) {
            if(hitObject.collider.name == bed.name) {
                Debug.Log(hitObject.collider.name);
                rayDir *= -1;
                facingRight = true;
                Flip();
            }
            if(hitObject.collider.name == bar.name) {
                Debug.Log(hitObject.collider.name);
                rayDir *= -1;
                facingRight = false;
                Flip();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Move()
    {
        // rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        base.Move();
        if(facingRight == false) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-1, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(1,rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
```

Like @Prodigle said, I had a boolean that I changed in order to flip the sprite.